# How did this character exist in the new universe created in Crisis?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, crossovers, green-arrow

In the final part of "Crisis on Infinite Earths", in the beginning of the episode, when Barry and Kara first found out that

> nobody remembered the multiverse

when the guy asked for an autograph, he mentioned that Barry and Kara were usually accompanied by

> Green Arrow

and a couple of Legends.

My question is this; how did the guy know about

> Green Arrow

?

> Was it a different Green Arrow (not Oliver Queen, maybe Mia?). From my understanding, Oliver sacrificed himself to create the new universe, so he would never have existed in the new one, so the guy wouldn't know him.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the episode, the president gives a speech in which she mentions how Oliver Queen, the Green Arrow sacrificed himself in the fight to save the Universe. This speech treats him as a well-known hero, so it seems that Oliver did exist in this new Universe up until the same time he died in the original Universe. Note also that they have his costume at the end, again suggesting that there was someone using it.

It's possible that the remaining two episodes of Arrow will fill in some more details of how everything fits together, but it definitely doesn't seem like Oliver was erased from history.